# How to calculate days between positive and negative results and creating new columns for each with R

Tags: r, if-statement, transform, apply, mutate

I have looked for answer to this but I have not been able to find one that will help me with a column that has numbers and strings.  My data look like this

```
Name <- c("Doe, John","Doe, John","Doe, John", "Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane","Doe, Jane","Parker, Peter","Parker, Peter","Parker, Peter", "Stark, Tony","Stark, Tony","Stark, Tony")
Accession <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789, 8910, 1023, 1134, 1567, 1769)
MRN <-c(55555, 55555, 55555, 66666, 66666, 66666, 77777, 77777, 77777, 88888, 88888, 88888)
Collected <-c("2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-10", "2022-01-11", "2022-01-12", "2022-01-13", "2022-01-14", "2022-01-15", "2022-01-16")
Result <-c(137, "Not Detected", 356, 1025, 1405, 538, "Not Detected", "Not Detected", "Not Detected", "Not Detected", 137, "Not Detected")

CV <- data.frame(Name, Accession, MRN, Collected, Result)
```

I have multiple observations on a group of people (sometimes up to 100 per person) I would like to begin counting from their first observation based on the date when they have a positive result and I would like to make this a new column `Days_till_Pos`, from that first positive result date I would then like to count the number of days until the results is "Not Detected" creating a new column `Days_till_Neg`.

I would like the data to look like this, where the results are grouped by `MRN`.

In this scenario if there is a number value in the `Result` column it would be considered positive, if it says "Not Detected" it would be considered negative. Also, If their first result is positive then the `Days_till_Pos` should say `NA` and if they never have a positive result then the `Days_till_Neg` column should say `NA` as well.

```
Name<- c("Doe, John","Doe, Jane","Parker, Peter", "Stark, Tony")
MRN<- c(55555, 66666, 77777, 88888)
Days_till_Pos<- c(NA, NA, NA, 1)
Days_till_Neg<- c(1,0,NA, 1)

CV1<- data.frame(Name, MRN, Days_till_Pos, Days_till_Neg)

Name                MRN          Days_till_Pos          Days_till_Neg
Doe,John            55555              NA                    1
Doe, Jane           66666              NA                    0
Parker, Peter       77777              NA                    NA 
Stark, Tony         88888              1                     1
```

Comment: The only row in your expected output that makes sense to me is the fourth. `John` is positive immediately, shouldn't `Pos` be 0? Peter has no positives, why is `Neg` 1, shouldn't it be 0 or NA?

Comment: @r2evans Yes you are correct the response should have been NA, I have updated the data and question to reflect that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is correct, but happy to modify further as needed.

The first `mutate` is to make sure you have `Collected` in date format.

After grouping by `Name` and `MRN`, you can use summarise for each patient.

For `Days_till_Pos`, check if the first `Result` is negative. If it is, then take the difference between the first collection date when positive, and the first collection date (which is known to be negative). Alternatively, if first result is positive, then just include `NA`.

For `Days_till_Neg`, check if `all` results are negative. If so, include `NA`. If not, then take the date for when the `Result` is negative, but the `lag` (previous date) result was positive. This would provide the date of transition from positive to negative. Then subtract the first date of a positive test.

Note that this assumes that patients do not oscillate multiple times between negative and positive tests.

```
library(tidyverse)

CV %>%
  mutate(Collected = as.Date(Collected)) %>%
  group_by(Name, MRN) %>%
  summarise(
    Days_till_Pos = ifelse(first(Result) == "Not Detected", 
                           Collected[Result != "Not Detected"][1] - Collected[1], 
                           NA),
    Days_till_Neg = ifelse(all(Result == "Not Detected"), 
                           NA, 
                           Collected[Result == "Not Detected" & lag(Result, default = "Not Detected") != "Not Detected"][1] - Collected[Result != "Not Detected"][1])
  )
```

**Output**

```
  Name            MRN Days_till_Pos Days_till_Neg
  <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Doe, Jane     66666            NA            NA
2 Doe, John     55555            NA             1
3 Parker, Peter 77777            NA            NA
4 Stark, Tony   88888             1             1
```

Comment: thank you!  What about if I want to know the total number of days a person is positive?  This could include 20+ tests over one year in some instances.

Comment: @T.McMillen Is it possible to go back/forth from positive to negative to positive multiple times? Or just one long 20 day continuous series of a positive test result?

Comment: It is possible for them to back/forth usually only once (pos/neg/pos or neg/pos/neg)

Comment: @T.McMillen If pos/neg/pos - which days are counted? Just the first pos until negative (and ignore the second group of positive)? Or all positive?

Comment: Actually, it would be great if I could capture all three day counts.

Comment: You can try adding to `summarise` something like: `Days_Positive = ifelse(all(Result != "Not Detected"),
                           last(Collected) - first(Collected) + 1,
                           last(Collected[Result != "Not Detected"]) - first(Collected[Result != "Not Detected" & lag(Result, default = "") == "Not Detected"]) + 1)`

Comment: In this case, if all results are numeric (none are "not detected"), then just take last date and subtract first date (add 1 to be inclusive)...

Comment: Otherwise, take the last date of a positive result and subtract the first date of a positive result (where the previous row as negative, transition from negative to positive)